# Who makes quiet ATX horizontal cases?

Tags: noise, case, atx

Who makes quiet ATX horizontal cases?

I am building a new PC, but even the smallest mid-towers have room for 3 5.25" drives and even more 3.5" drives.

I am thinking a horizontal case just big enough to fit an ATX motherboard, CPU FAN and a Geforce 560Ti should so the trick and be much smaller in terms of volume.

I just can't find any quality cases that emphasize silence.

Can anyone make any suggestions?
I'm thinking there are smaller brands such as Fractal Design out there that are not as well known as Antec and Gigabyte, but that might make a great product.

**EDIT:** This is currently my [favorite](http://www.fractal-design.com/?view=product&category=2&prod=58), but it's still a tower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out [Silent PC Review](http://www.silentpcreview.com/).  That said, if you're really concerned about noise, consider finding a case you like *and just replacing the fans in it with quieter ones*.  Very few cases come with decent fans, to be honest - I don't even like the ones in high end Lian Li cases for acoustics.
EDIT: You can always add acoustic dampening foam, as well.

Comment: The #1 key to buying quiet fans: Never buy a fan smaller than 120mm in diameter. In general, any case that makes a serious attempt to be quiet will not come with any 80mm fans.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you get a good answer, but if you don't...

ATX cases are everywhere and whilst there are exceptions to every rule, people usually buy ATX because they want maximum flexibility - every pci/pci-express socket, loads of hard drive sockets etc.

You can find a large variety of cases (silent, see through, highly mod-able), but typically they revolve around the core reason for buying ATX above, therefore, not usually small.

If you really want a quiet smaller case, you really need to look at M-ATX boards as these typically are aimed towards people with your expectations. They usually do not come in that many mod-able varieties compared to ATX cases, but they are smaller and you can get silent ones.